# Java - why does this input not generate ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, reflection, classnotfoundexception, linkageerror

While I am using reflection I came upon this error. I have a class named Test1, and when I try to get a Class object of it by entering test1 as input to Class.forName() it generates LinkageError instead of ClassNotFoundException. Why does the lower-case letter confuse the program and prevent it from generating the usual ClassNotFoundException as with for example "sjghdjgh"?

Minimal example

Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("test1");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.out.println(cnfe.toString());
        }
        catch (LinkageError le) {
            System.out.println(le.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Test1

```
public class Test1 {
}
```

Comment: how about sharing the code?

Comment: Probably because of file system case sensitivity issues.

Comment: Do you have the complete stack trace and exception message?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of trying to describe your code.

Comment: Ok, will do in a sec. This is the error.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test1 (wrong name: test1)

Comment: @DonkeyKing *"This is the error. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"* but in question you say *"it generates LinkageError instead of ClassNotFoundException"*, so which is it?

Comment: @Andreas NoClassDefFoundError is a subclass of LinkageError

Comment: Have added minimal code now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ask some file systems for `test1.class` they will give you back a `Test1.class` instead of a file-not-found (because they are case-insensitive) and then that class file does not contain a class called `test1`, but instead a `Test1` (Java class names are case-sensitive), so that the classloader errors out.

This is rarely a problem in practice, because most applications are deployed using Jar files (so that there are no individual files for the classes in the filesystem).

Comment: So if I run that program on a Linux computer (I am using windows) I would get the ClassNotFoundException?